# How can I replicate the rotation and animation effects I see in the Twitter iPad app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, animation, twitter

I wish to replicate the effect I see in the iPad Twitter application, thus:

[image]

How?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a broad one, so I'll give a broad answer:

Screen rotation is handled automatically by your app. (There is a method to implement for  that though.)

The rest of the UI is probably scroll views and nested table views.